# Automating Raw Export Data Cleansing for Client Onboarding - Format is Always Different

Tags: excel, vba, automation, export-to-csv, data-cleaning

So a bit of a general question. I work as a data analyst for a startup. My primary process involves taking existing customer data a client has and cleansing/normalizing it to fit into our platform once as part of our onboarding process. A member of our team exports their data from their system they are transitioning from or, if they kept track of it in house, we receive their Excel log they used to track it. It is always in a different format and requires extensive cleansing (avg 1 min/record). We take what is usually one large table (.xlxs format), and after cleansing, split it into four .csv files; which we load as four tables on our platform.

I feel I have optimized the process quite well in terms of the process steps and cleansing with excel functions (if, concat, text-to-columns, etc). I have beginner-intermediate skills in VBA and SQL and have just scratched the surface in R; what is frustrating is that I know there is the potential to automate this process but I just don't know where to start. If anyone has experience with something like this, code, a link to an article / another thread, or just some general direction would be much appreciated. Please ask for clarification where you feel it is needed. Thanks.

Comment: If the data is constantly changing format, the first step in automating it is to explain to the client how they can keep your costs down (and therefore what you are charging them) by **not** changing format all the time.  Until they give you consistent data, you will always have a lot of manual work to do.

Comment: Identify one specific commonly-performed step or process, generalize it to cover a few sub-types of that process, then try to code that one thing. Post back with your code if you run into problems and people will likely help. It's difficult to be more specific than that, not knowing what it is you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

This will be really hard to do in Excel. If you have the time you can try out Optimus, a Data Cleansing library written in Python and Pyspark (you don't need to know spark). Here is the webpage https://hioptimus.com.

You can create Data Pipelines with it, and I recommend that you do that, try to generalize your processes, and asking the client for more a structure way of passing the data.

The good thing is that you don't need Big Data for running Optimus, bit if you have it some day, the same code will work.

Check out the documentation for more:

http://optimus-ironmussa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Let me know if you have doubts!